# How do I output which iteration of a loop the code is running

Tags: java, loops

I have a question about loops. I am creating a program that calculates the deprecation of an asset(It is unknown), and I am looping it so it runs 4 times. The whole code looks like this

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class  Program108b{

     public static void main(String[] args){
         int [] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4};
         for(int x: numbers){
             Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

             System.out.print("  Enter price ");
             double price = kb.nextDouble();

             System.out.print("Enter salvage value ");
             double salValue = kb.nextDouble();
             System.out.print("Enter estimated life in years ");
             int years = kb.nextInt();
             double anws = ((price- salValue)/years);
             System.out.print("Here is the depreciated value: " + (Math.round((anws)*100)/100.0));
         }
     }
 }
```

I am trying to make it say "run #1", then "run #2", then "run #3", and then "run #4" at the top of the code when that certain run happens. So right now the output is

```
Enter price 2500
Enter salvage value 350
Enter estimated life in years 23
Here is the depreciated value: 93.48  Enter price 23
Enter salvage value 
32
Enter estimated life in years 3
Here is the depreciated value: -3.0  Enter price 2
Enter salvage value 32
Enter estimated life in years 3
Here is the depreciated value: -10.0  Enter price 23
Enter salvage value 2
Enter estimated life in years 3
Here is the depreciated value: 7.0
```

(The input is totally random, I just wanted to show what the output is)
I want to make the output look like this:

```
run #1    
Enter price 2500
Enter salvage value 350
Enter estimated life in years 23
Here is the depreciated value: 93.48
run #2
Enter price 23
Enter salvage value 
32
Enter estimated life in years 3
Here is the depreciated value: -3.0 
run #3
Enter price 2
Enter salvage value 32
Enter estimated life in years 3
Here is the depreciated value: -10.0  
run #4
Enter price 23
Enter salvage value 2
Enter estimated life in years 3
Here is the depreciated value: 7.0
```

So my question is- how would I make it say "run #_", and have it change each loop to "run #1", "run #2", etc until the forth run? Also, how would I make the start of a new run begin on a new line (the "enter price" part in this code)?

Comment: System.out.print doesn't add a new line.  System.out.println does.  Or you can also add "\n" in the print string to manually add a new line.   This should help you clean things up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add a `System.out.println` at the beginning of loop

```
for (int x: numbers) {
    System.out.println("run #" + x);
    // Rest of code
}
```

Comment: Thank you. but how would I start the program on a new line?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class  Program108b {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    for(int x: numbers){
      System.out.println("run #" + x);    /// Add this
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("  Enter price ");
      double price = kb.nextDouble();

      System.out.print("Enter salvage value ");
      double salValue = kb.nextDouble();

      System.out.print("Enter estimated life in years ");
      int years = kb.nextInt();

      double anws = ((price- salValue)/years);
      System.out.print("Here is the depreciated value: " + (Math.round((anws)*100)/100.0));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class  Program108b{

     public static void main(String[] args){
         int [] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4};
         for(int x: numbers){
              System.out.print("run #_" + x);
             Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

             System.out.print("  Enter price ");
             double price = kb.nextDouble();

             System.out.print("Enter salvage value ");
             double salValue = kb.nextDouble();
             System.out.print("Enter estimated life in years ");
             int years = kb.nextInt();
             double anws = ((price- salValue)/years);
             System.out.print("Here is the depreciated value: " + (Math.round((anws)*100)/100.0));
         }
     }
 }

or create a variable and add 1 to it on every iteration

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class  Test1{

     public static void main(String[] args){
         int [] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4};
         int iteration = 0;
         for(int x: numbers){
             System.out.println("run #"+ ++iteration);
             Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

             System.out.print("  Enter price ");
             double price = kb.nextDouble();

             System.out.print("Enter salvage value ");
             double salValue = kb.nextDouble();
             System.out.print("Enter estimated life in years ");
             int years = kb.nextInt();
             double anws = ((price- salValue)/years);
             System.out.print("Here is the depreciated value: " + (Math.round((anws)*100)/100.0));
         }
     }
 }
```